# Passing variables to range patterns in awk

Tags: shell-script, awk, variable-substitution

I'm trying to use range patterns in awk:

```
grep -a volume somefile | awk '/^Apr 25 23:44:04*/,/^Apr 26 12:44:01*/ {print}'
```

This works fine, but when I try to execute it by putting the date and time in variables and execute it doesn't seem to work:

```
time1="Apr 25 23:44:04"
time2="Apr 26 12:44:01"
grep -a volume somefile | awk '/^"$time1"*/,/^"$time2"*/ {print}'
```

Answer (score 2):

Because the shell variables inside a single-quoted string, they will not be expanded.  It doesn't matter that the single-quoted string includes double-quotes inside of it, it is still a single-quoted string.

Use instead:

```
grep -a volume somefile | awk "/^$time1/,/^$time2/ {print}"
```

Actually, since `print` is the *default* action, one can simplify that to:

```
grep -a volume somefile | awk "/^$time1/,/^$time2/"
```

You do need to be careful with this approach.  You must make sure that neither `time1` nor `time2` contain unintentional awk-active characters.

A safer approach is to transfer the shell variables to awk variables:

```
grep -a volume somefile | awk -v t1="$time1" -v t2="$time2" '($0~"^"t1),($0~"^"t2)'
```

Note that, even in this safer approach, as Gilles notes in the comments, you still must be careful: if the strings in `time1` and `time2` were to contain the characters `^*+.?\[|{$`, the strings would be interpreted as regular expressions.  This is not a problem for the strings shown in the question (they contain no regex-active characters) but, if other strings were to give you surprising results, this is a likely cause.